# How To Get Google Calendar Events only for a specific date range

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using OAuth to authenticate with Google Calendar and the PHP Client Library, using the example bellow, I was able to get all events from the "primary" calendar. Is there a way to specify a date range, for example, I'd like to get only events that will appear in future.

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');

while(true) {
  foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    echo $event->getSummary();
  }
  $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
  if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these parameters for range filtering:

- timeMin
- timeMax

Note that time must be formated with date(DateTime::ATOM).

Comment: can you give me example of using parameters ?